# How to check that all elements in a list are unique

Tags: python, list, loops, pairwise

How can i write a program to check that all elements in a list are unique.
I have a list that is entered by the user and i would like the program to check that the elements are unique, if they are, say list=[1,2,3,4,5], then the program continues. If not, say list=[1,2,3,4,5,5,5], then the user must reenter the list.
Thankyou

Comment: `if len(set(your_list)) != len(your_list): #Ask input`

Answer (score 2):

This link has explained in details
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-check-if-list-contains-all-unique-elements/

```
# to check all unique list elements 
flag = len(set(test_list)) == len(test_list)
```